# SharePoint Online sites name

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site, site-settings, settings

How can I rename a SharePoint online (Office 365) site?

I need to know if it is possible or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it site collection or subsite ?

Comment: Need more clarity, by site name what you are referring to?

Comment: You could change the title of the site. Go to site settings->click “Title, description, and logo”->add the site name in the title textbox. It just changes title of the site not the url of the site.
Then you could create a new site collection with the name which you want and delete the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with private site collections on SharePoint Online currently.

This is because of the SSL requirement (in the E plans) for private site collections. There isn't a way to upload an SSL cert to SharePoint Online so that it can serve requests for that domain and HTTPS.

You can map your vanity domain to your SharePoint Online public web site however (because it doesn't use HTTPS).

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible to rename the SharePoint Online site collections.